# SalatDAO does not deserialize BasicDBList properly

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

I have a case class who's one of the properties if of type `JValue`.

During serialization, it gets converted to `BasicDBList` (regardless of what was it's value, even it if was just a `JString` - this is odd, but set that aside...)

So saving the object to the database (Mongodb) works fine, but when I try to `findOne()`, I'm getting the following error:

```
argument type mismatch

          $anon$2(class com.example.data.Telemetry @ com.novus.salat.global.package$$anon$1@7376d6c3) toObject failed on:
          SYM: com.example.data.Telemetry
          CONSTRUCTOR
        public com.example.data.Telemetry(java.lang.String,org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue)

        ---------- CONSTRUCTOR EXPECTS FOR PARAM [1] --------------
        NAME:         location
        TYPE:         org.json4s.JsonAST$JValue
        DEFAULT ARG   [Missing, but unnecessary because input value was supplied]
        @Ignore       false
        ---------- CONSTRUCTOR INPUT ------------------------
        TYPE: com.mongodb.BasicDBList
        VALUE:
        [ [ [ &quot;latitude&quot; , [ 34.001]] , [ &quot;longitude&quot; , [ 32.511]]]]
        ------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it seems like the object does not get deserialized properly (from `BasicDBList` back to `JValue`). This works fine one what, but the other way seems broken.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salat has no special handling / conversions for `org.json4s` classes. Because `JString` is a case class, ultimately Salat delegates to the default encoder in Casbah converts your `JString` to a `java.util.List`

https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/9f3ebe8e389a9cf91cc6ce1591b3950898e895a7/casbah-commons/src/main/scala/conversions/ScalaConversions.scala#L361

Later, when Salat attempts to extract it from the DBObject, it similarly doesn't have any logic for converting it from a DBList to a JString.

If you have to stay with a `JString`, I recommend you consider implementing a custom converter and registering it with your Salat context.  Examples here:

https://github.com/novus/salat/blob/master/salat-core/src/test/scala/com/novus/salat/test/custom/model.scala

https://github.com/novus/salat/blob/master/salat-core/src/test/scala/com/novus/salat/test/CustomTransformerSpec.scala